# git rebase with 'ours' merge strategy prompting to rebase --continue again and again

Tags: git-merge-conflict, git

Here is the issue I am facing

I had created a feature branch from the `master` branch. I worked extensively on a feature branch, it is 80 odd commits ahead of the master branch. In these commits, I have edited some files multiple times. After a few days, someone pushed a couple of commits on the master branch thus Pull Request of the feature branch can't be merged due to merge conflicts.

I tried rebase to master and resolve the merge conflict, but I am getting more and more conflicts after `git rebase --continue`

```
govi@falcon:/home/my_user/project/ (feature/xyz): git rebase master
govi@falcon:/home/my_user/project/ (feature/xyz | REBASE 32/85):
```

Here for any merge conflict, I want to select my changes. so I tried `ours` conflicts resolution strategy in recursive mode. Now git is not forcing me to resolve any conflicts but it is asking me to execute `git rebase --continues`  almost 80 odd times.

```
govi@falcon:/home/my_user/project/ (feature/xyz): git rebase master -s recursive -X ours
govi@falcon:/home/my_user/project/ (feature/xyz | REBASE-i 1/85)
Last command done (1 command done):
     pick db2511c Modify file
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
     pick d1c2037 Modify file one more time
```

is there a better approach to resolve merge conflicts in the above scenario? or maybe a better way to rebase?

PS: We are not allowed to reset the master branch. I know easy way would be to perform `{reset, stash, rebase, pop}` on the feature branch, but PR is already in progress.

Comment: Do you understand *why* you get conflicts? Using a mere "ours" strategy hints at that you do not, and that you are just using the sledgehammer because you own it. In practice, it is a vast minority of cases where "ours" is the correct conflict resolution.

Comment: Most of the conflicts are in logger statements and after internal discussion, it turns out that my branch's changes are the ones needed and can be overridden thus "ours" strategy seems to be a good strategy here.

Comment: Good. Using "ours" sounds like a reasonable choice in this case. Are the merge conflicts that you observe always at the same spot, or are conflicts from different commits in spots that you have not visited in earlier commits? Because if you did everything correctly, then I would not expect a merge conflict to reappear in a spot where you have already resolved it with "ours" in an earlier commit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## TL;DR

You really want `-X theirs`.  *Why* you want that is ... long.

## Long

First, an initial side note: be careful with terminology: you are not using the `ours` *strategy* but rather the `ours` *strategy option*.  I find Git's terminology here confusing, and prefer to call these `-X` options *extended options*, to avoid repeating the word *strategy*.

Now, on to the problem itself.  When using `git rebase`, you are, in effect, repeatedly running `git cherry-pick`.  Each cherry-pick operation copies one commit; `git rebase` works by copying multiple commits.  The `git rebase` command first lists out all the hash IDs of the commits that are to be copied, saving these into internal "to-do" files.  These files then get updated as the rebase makes progress.

(The details for these files have changed over the years and there's no real point in describing them.  However, your shell prompt settings appear to read these to-do and progress files correctly, based on the "1/85" and "32/85" you're seeing here.)

A cherry-pick operation is, technically, a full-blown three-way merge, and can therefore produce merge conflicts.  But one must be quite careful here.  You wrote:

```
git rebase master -s recursive -X ours
```

The *strategy* argument to `git merge` or `git rebase` is `-s` or `--strategy`; you are using `recursive` here, which is fine (an `ours` *strategy* is not).  The extended options are `-X`, and an `ours` or `theirs` *extended option* does make sense—but there's a trap here: you want `-X theirs`.

#### What's going on

Before we dive into cherry-pick, let's look at `git merge`.  Without this first look at `git merge`, some of what cherry-pick does makes no sense at all.

To do a `git merge` operation, we start with a series of commits where, e.g., two different developers started with the *same initial chain of commits:*

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

These two developers, [who we'll call Alice and Bob in the usual way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob), have each made some new commits.  I'll work here from Alice's point of view:

```
       I--J   <-- alice (HEAD)
      /
...--H
      \
       K--L   <-- bob
```

At this point, Alice might merge Bob's work.  She has her commit `J` checked out, with the special name `HEAD` attached to the branch name `alice`; she now runs `git merge bob` to merge Bob's commit `L`.

The `git merge` command—technically, this is the `recursive` strategy rather than `git merge` itself—locates commit `L` using the branch name `bob`.  This commit becomes the *third* commit.  Git locates commit `J` using the special name `HEAD`, and this becomes the *second* commit.  Last—which becomes first—it works *backwards through the commit graph* to locate the *best common commit*, which in this case is commit `H`.

Each commit has a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about when whoever made the commit, made the commit.  So Git can now easily compare the snapshot in the merge base commit `H` against the snapshot in Alice's commit `J`, and then do the same thing with Bob's commit `L`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what Alice changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what Bob changed
```

Note that the three commits in question here are:

1. commit `H`, as the merge base;
2. commit `J`, as `--ours`, via `HEAD`; and
3. commit `L`, as `--theirs`, via the name `bob`.

The merge command—the *merge as a verb* part of it, that is—now *combines* our changes, `H`-vs-`J`, with their changes, `H`-vs-`L`.  It is this combining process that can produce merge conflicts.

To the extent that there *aren't* merge conflicts, though, Git can automatically apply the combined changes, to the files as seen in the merge base commit `H`.  This keeps our changes while adding their changes, which is of course just what we want from a merge.

When there *are* merge conflict, `git merge` stops in the middle of the merge.  It leaves in Git's index all three input files: index slot #1 contains the base commit copy, slot #2 contains the `--ours` copy from `HEAD`, and slot #3 contains the `--theirs` copy from the commit we named with our `git merge` command.

Git writes, to the work-tree version of the conflicted file, its best effort at doing the combination.  Places where Git was able to combine changes on its own already contain that combination.  Places where Git found an ours-vs-theirs conflict have conflict markers and two, or even all three, input files' lines, depending on how you set `merge.conflictStyle`.

I call these kinds of conflicts *low level* conflicts.  (Git calls them that internally, sort of.)  There are also what I call *high level* conflicts, such as when one side—ours or theirs—modifies and/or renames a file, and the other side deletes it.

Using an extended option, `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, tells Git: *when you hit a low-level conflict, just resolve it by taking ours or theirs respectively.*  This has no effect on high level conflicts: you must still resolve these manually.

Note that low-level conflicts can occur even if the two changes don't both change the *same* line.  For instance, if the original input says:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

and Alice changes `2` to `two` while Bob changes `3` to `three`, Git will call this a *merge conflict*.  Using `-X ours` or `-X theirs` will discard one of the two changes.  It's a good idea to actually test such merges before moving on.  (Well, it's a good idea to test *any* merge: just because Git thought that it was OK to combine two different sets of changes, does not mean that it really *was* OK.)

#### Recap

The takeaways from the above—re-read through it if needed—are:

- The `-s strategy` is in charge of all the work; we're talking here about `-s recursive` (though `-s resolve` does the same kind of thing).
- A merge operation has three inputs: base = #1, `ours` or HEAD = #2, `theirs` = #3.
- Git will combine unconflicted changes on its own, regardless of `-X` options.
- Git will stop with high-level conflicts, regardless of `-X` options.
- The `-X` options will favor either "ours" (#1-vs-#2) or "theirs" (#1-vs-#3) to resolve low-level conflicts.

#### Cherry-pick

We're now ready to look at what `git cherry-pick` really does.  The action for a cherry-pick is often described as *repeat the changes from a previous commit*.  While this captures the *goal*, it doesn't cover the *mechanism*.  The mechanism is irrelevant up until a merge conflict occurs, and then suddenly it's terribly important.

To talk about the mechanism, let's draw another commit graph fragment.  This time, instead of Alice and Bob diverging from some common starting point `H`, let's just look at one or two programmers working on two different features, for instance:

```
...--P--C--N--O   <-- feature1

...--R--S--T   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

Commit `C` is the child of parent commit `P`; commit `N` comes after `C` and `O` comes after `P`; these are all found through the name `feature1`.

Commit `T` is the last commit on `feature2`, and we have branch `feature2` checked out right now.  So commit `T` is the `HEAD` commit.

We need some new code to apply to `T`, and we realize: *Wait, I just **saw** that code, or wrote it last week.  It was in commit `C`!*  So we run `git log` to find the actual hash ID of commit `C`, then run:

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>
```

to copy that commit.

In order to *do* the copying—to find out what changed between parent commit `P` and child commit `C`—Git will run the same `git diff --find-renames` that we saw above with `git merge`.  But that just gets *their change*.  In order to apply their change to our commit, Git will first run another `git diff --find-renames`, this time comparing parent `P` with our current / HEAD commit `T`.

In other words, Git runs:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-P> <hash-of-T>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-P> <hash-of-C>   # what they changed
```

and now Git *combines the changes*, using the same merge engine as usual (`-s recursive`), and applies the combined changes to the snapshot in `P`.  This preserves our work, and adds their change.  Commit `P` becomes the merge base, and commit `T` is the `--ours` while `C` is the `--theirs`.

Merge conflicts, if any occur, are because of these two `git diff` operations.  If they do occur, index slot #1 contains files from the merge base `P`, slot #2 contains ours from `T`, and slot #3 contains theirs from `T`.  The `--ours` option to `git checkout` makes sense, because `T` really is *our* commit.  The `-X ours` option makes sense, because `T` is our commit.

#### Rebase

As mentioned above, the way `git rebase` works is to list out the commit hash IDs of some series of commits that need to be copied.  Then it uses Git's *detached HEAD* mode to check out one particular commit.  For illustration, let's draw a small rebase with just three commits to do:

```
       C--D--E   <-- branch (HEAD)
      /
...--B--F--G   <-- mainline
```

Here, the commits we'd like copied are `C`, `D`, and `E`.  The old base was commit `B`.  Commits `F` and `G` got added to the mainline branch.  So we run:

```
git checkout branch
git rebase mainline
```

Git uses the current commit `E` and works backwards to find the three commits to copy, while using the name `mainline` and working backwards to find that commit `B` is the shared commit at which the copying stops.  Then, Git uses the name `mainline` to get into detached HEAD mode:

```
       C--D--E   <-- branch
      /
...--B--F--G   <-- HEAD, mainline
```

Git is now ready to copy commit `C`.  Internally, at this point, Git runs `git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>` and `git cherry-pick` does its thing.

If all goes well, the "merge" that cherry-pick runs works: Git compares base `B` with "our" commit `G`, compares base `B` with "their" commit `C`, combines the two differences on top of commit `B`, and makes a new commit that we will call `C'`:

```
       C--D--E   <-- branch
      /
...--B--F--G   <-- mainline
            \
             C'  <-- HEAD
```

Git now repeats this with commit `D`.  The "merge" uses commit `C` as its merge base, `C'` as `--ours`, and `D` as `--theirs`.  Git combines the changes, applies the combined changes to existing commit `C'`, and makes new commit `D'`:

```
       C--D--E   <-- branch
      /
...--B--F--G   <-- mainline
            \
             C'-D'  <-- HEAD
```

Git now cherry-picks `E`: `D` is the merge base, `D'` is `--ours`, and `E` is `--theirs`, and the new commit completes the copying process:

```
       C--D--E   <-- branch
      /
...--B--F--G   <-- mainline
            \
             C'-D'-E'  <-- HEAD
```

With the copying done, `git rebase` now only needs to yank the name `branch` off the old tip commit `E`, and make it point to the commit that `HEAD` currently names, i.e., `E'`, and re-attach `HEAD` to make everything look normal:

```
       C--D--E   [abandoned]
      /
...--B--F--G   <-- mainline
            \
             C'-D'-E'  <-- branch (HEAD)
```

#### Note what `--ours` means

During the cherry-picking part of a rebase, `--ours` referred to:

- commit `G`, at first
- then commit `C'`,
- and then commit `D'`.

So `--ours` refers first to their commit `G`, then to our own commits *as built on the new branch*.

The `--theirs` commits were, in order, `C`, then `D`, then `E`.  So `--theirs` refers to *our* commits, always.

The merge base commits were, in order, `B`, then `C`, then `D`.  There's no `--base` option to refer to these, but the first one was "their" commit and the other two were ours.

If we want to override "their" (`mainline`) branch changes, then, we need to use `--theirs`, not `--ours`, most of the time.